# zf2 set duration of auth session

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am trying to set the duration of a authentication session but I have no success on it.

I have set the follow code to set a small session time;

> $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(array('username',
>   'id', 'role', 'firstname', 'lastname')));
>
> $sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();
>
> $sessionManager->rememberMe(time(100));

But the session is way longer than I configured. What am I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing the result of the php `time` function. That function has no parameters and it always returns the current unix timestamp. Maybe try `$sessionManager->rememberMe(100);` instead

Comment: Great! This does the trick :)